# Content-Disposition header Azure HTTP trigger function

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, xlsx, azure-http-trigger

Basically iam trying to get an excel as a response from an HTTP triggered azure function

```
response = func.HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.xlsx"'
return response
```

but there is no header for Content -Disposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use this code:

```
response = func.HttpResponse(fileContent, headers={'Content-Disposition':'attachment; filename="test.xlsx"'}, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387470/7641854