# Return Excel file from Azure Function via HTTP using Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, http, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

### Use Case

Within a Logic App, I create some data using an Azure Function with a Pandas DataFrame. After employing the Azure Function, I want to further process the data in .xlsx format within the Logic App. Therefore I need the Azure Function to return an .xlsx file.

### Problem

I am unable to format the `HTTPResponse` of my Azure Function so that I can further process the .xlsx file within the Logic App. Basically I require the correct conversion from my Pandas DataFrame to the HTTPResponse.

**What to do in `convert_to_xlsx()` (see below) to achieve the desired output?**

### Toy Example

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(2, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    
    excel = convert_to_xlsx(df)

    return func.HttpResponse(excel, status_code=200)

def convert_to_xlsx(df):
    # Create excel representation
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active

    for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
        sheet.append(row)
        
    logging.info('sheet: ' + str(list(sheet.values))) # So far, so good.   
    
    # Convert for HTTPResponse
    res = ''
    res = do_something(sheet) # <---- What to do here?
    return res
```

### What I tried

I tried converting the data to openpyxl's `Workbook`, which worked fine. But then I did not know how to proceed from here to convert from a `Workbook`.

Also, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482950/load-a-xlsb-file-from-azure-function-app/57506934#57506934) answer using xlrd, which I could not get to work for my use case. Additionally, xlrd [does not support .xlsx anymore](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/). Based on that post, I tried the following, which did not work as intended:

```py
def convert_to_xlsx(df):
    # ... see above
    # Only returns column names without values.
    # Also, apparently not the right format?
    return f'{[row for row in sheet]}'
```

One option might be to return some kind of JSON response and then convert it back to an excel file within the logic app. But I hoped that I might be able to skip that and immediately return a .xlsx file from the function as HTTP payload.

Comment: Why don’t you return the data itself (not in an excel format) and then push it to Excel within PowerAutomate?

Comment: I would like the function to be more self contained, i.e., not having to post-process its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach could be to write the output to a buffer and return the buffer's content within the `HTTPResponse`

```py
...
from io import BytesIO

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(2, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    buffer = BytesIO()
    excel_buf = df.to_excel(buffer)
    return func.HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), status_code=200)
```

However, due to concerns regarding file size and execution times for returning large files via http, I opted for uploading the resulting excel to an Azure BLOB storage, by using something like (snippet):

```py
...
out_blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(...)
excel_buf = df.to_excel(buffer)
out_blob.upload_blob(buffer.getvalue())
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain an Excel file you also have to manipulate the header, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67276395/7641854.

Without the changed header you will obtain a zip object I assume.

Thus a working example to return an Excelfile via Azure function looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    excel_buf = df.to_excel(buffer, index=False)

    return func.HttpResponse(
        buffer.getvalue(),
        headers={"Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="test.xlsx"'},
        mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel',
        status_code=200,
    )
```