# Python how to return an excel file without converting to bytes using HttpResponse

Tags: python, excel, azure-functions, httpresponse, azure-http-trigger

We want to return an excel file from python to the front-end. The way were are doing it now is as follows in an azure http trigger function.

```
return func.HttpResponse(
            customizedFile,
            headers={"Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="{customizedFileName}"'},
            mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel',
            status_code=200,
        )
```

The motive to return a file is to preserve file formatting. As there is another way in converting the workbook as bytes and send them back as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72632654/return-excel-file-from-azure-function-via-http-using-python):

```
buffer = BytesIO()
excel_buf = df.to_excel(buffer)
return func.HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), status_code=200)
```

Our aim to preserve the formatting after the needed cutomization.

Also we don't want to save in a blob as the end user should not have access to our storage.

The way mentioned at the top of the post is returning the following error:

> response is expected to be either of str, bytes, or bytearray, got
> Workbook

The returned file is saved successfully in a local directory.

How can we send the file as excel only without the need to convert to bytes. Is it something to fix from the front end to accept such types?

Answer (score 0):

- one work around you can do is to run a flask app on top of the azure function. This way you can use the `send_file()` function from the flask to send the file without using the buffer.
- to do this first your `__init__.py` in the HTTP trigger should look like this

```
import  azure.functions  as  func

// FlaskApp is the folder name in which the flask api file is located
from  FlaskApp  import  app

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return  func.WsgiMiddleware(app.wsgi_app).handle(req, context)
```

- Here we are basically running the middleware which will redirect the request to our flask app.
- We also have to edit the `function.json` and `host.json` basically we are configuring routing here.

function.json

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings":[
        {
            "authLevel": "anonymous",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "req",
            "methods":[
                "get",
                "post"
            ],
            "route": "{*route}"
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}
```

host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging":{
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "extentionBundle":{
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
    },
    "extentions":{
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        }
    }
}
```

- Now we can create the flask app here I have created the api in a `__init__.py` file which itself is in `FlaskApp` folder

`__init.py`(FLask)

```
from  flask  import  Flask
from  flask  import  send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def  welcome():
    return  send_file('C:\\Users\\v-mganorkar\\BackEndLearning\\testY\\test.xlsx')

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

[image]

- Now even if you don't want to use the `send_file()` function still the flask api will give you a lot of freedom to configuration the api the way you want without the loss of configuration.

Comment: What are the differences in the new host and function JSONs? Also note that instead of the the path mentioned I think we simply should use /tmp/test.xlsx as when deployed azure functions will work and have access over a temporary folder right?